# SDL_GetWindowPosition() doesn't update the int pointer

Tags: c++, sdl

I am trying to follow the tutorial on youtube to learn SDL. But when I tried to use SDL_GetWindowPosition() and SDL_GetWindowSize(), it seems didn't update the int*.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "include/SDL2/SDL.h"

using namespace std;

void CreateWindow(SDL_Window *win){
    win = SDL_CreateWindow("Title",
                           SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
                           SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
                           800, 600,
                           SDL_WINDOW_RESIZABLE);

    if (win == nullptr)
        cout<<"Could not create window.\n"<<SDL_GetError()<<'\n';
}

void QuitWindow(SDL_Window *win){
//    SDL_Delay(3000); // 3 seconds
    SDL_DestroyWindow(win);
    SDL_Quit();
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    // initialize window
    SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING );
    SDL_Window *win = nullptr;
    CreateWindow(win);


    // main loop
    SDL_Event event;
    bool run = true;
    while (run){
        int x, y, w, h;
        while (SDL_PollEvent(&event)){
            if (event.type == SDL_QUIT){
                run = false;
                QuitWindow(win);
                break;
            }
        }

        SDL_GetWindowPosition(win, &x, &y);
        SDL_GetWindowSize(win, &w, &h);
        cout<<x<<','<<y<<" ; "<<w<<','<<h<<endl;

    }

    return 0;
}
```

The results of cout are something like:
1048591,1872715060 ; 1,1965549662

I have tried to delete the main loop and simply create window -> getwindowposition -> getwindowsize -> quit. But still get similar results. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Pass pointer by reference: `SDL_Window *& win`. Now pointer in `CreateWindow` is passed by value, so you modify local copy of this pointer, original value of pointer is not affected.

Comment: I got a similar result after I change CreateWindow(win); to CreateWindow(*&win);  But QuitWindow(win); works fine. The window will be closed when I press 'X'.

Comment: Do this modification in definition of function, not when calling function. `void CreateWindow(SDL_Window *& win)`